# mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled

Tags: 20.04, cpu, temperature

I get this error message:

> mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled

I keep seeing these messages for all four cores on my fanless mini computer, yet the sensor command and i7z reports the temperatures are normal.

```
sensors
soc_dts0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +38.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +26.8°C  (crit = +90.0°C)

soc_dts1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +39.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +38.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +38.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +39.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:       +39.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Usually the PC will halt (crash) and a reboot will get things running again.
Any clue what could be wrong?

Below is the output of the two commands :

mini:~# grep model /proc/cpuinfo

```
model           : 55
model name      : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J1900  @ 1.99GHz
model           : 55
model name      : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J1900  @ 1.99GHz
model           : 55
model name      : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J1900  @ 1.99GHz
model           : 55
model name      : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J1900  @ 1.99GHz
```

root@mini:~# ps aux | grep -i therm

```
root         153  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Jul16   0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root       10642  0.1  0.1 123240 10128 ?        Ssl  18:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable
root       10656  0.0  0.0   6432   732 pts/1    S+   18:25   0:00 grep --color=auto -i therm
```

turbostat output:

```
turbostat version 19.08.31 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0xb CPUID levels; 0x80000008 xlevels; family:model:stepping 0x6:37:8 (6:55:8)
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR - EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, No-TURBO, DTS, No-PTM, No-HWP, No-HWPnotify, No-HWPwindow, No-HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, EPB
cpu0: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x4000840089 (TCC No-EIST MWAIT PREFETCH No-TURBO)
CPUID(7): No-SGX
SLM BCLK: 83.3 Mhz
cpu0: MSR_CC6_DEMOTION_POLICY_CONFIG: 0x00000000 (DISable-CC6-Demotion)
cpu0: MSR_MC6_DEMOTION_POLICY_CONFIG: 0x00000000 (DISable-MC6-Demotion)
RAPL: 4581 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 30 Watts
cpu0: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x100000001800
16 * 83.3 = 1332.8 MHz max efficiency frequency
24 * 83.3 = 1999.2 MHz base frequency
cpu0: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x00000000 (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_ATOM_CORE_RATIOS: 0x00181002
2 * 83.3 = 166.6 MHz minimum operating frequency
16 * 83.3 = 1332.8 MHz low frequency mode (LFM)
24 * 83.3 = 1999.2 MHz base frequency
cpu0: MSR_ATOM_CORE_TURBO_RATIOS: 0x1d1d1d1d
29 * 83.3 = 2415.7 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
29 * 83.3 = 2415.7 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
29 * 83.3 = 2415.7 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
29 * 83.3 = 2415.7 MHz max turbo 1 active core
cpu0: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x00040000 (UNlocked, pkg-cstate-limit=0 (pc0))
cpu0: POLL: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
cpu0: C1: MWAIT 0x00
cpu0: C6N: MWAIT 0x58
cpu0: C6S: MWAIT 0x52
cpu0: C7: MWAIT 0x60
cpu0: C7S: MWAIT 0x64
cpu0: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu0: cpufreq governor: powersave
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 1
cpu0: MSR_IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: 0x00000006 (balanced)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x00000505 (0.031250 Watts, 0.000032 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x003880fa (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (7.812500 Watts, 262144.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x00690000 (105 C)
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IRQ SMI POLL    C1  C6N C6S C7  C7S POLL%   C1% C6N%    C6S%    C7% C7S%    CPU%c1  CPU%c6  Mod%c6  CoreTmp GFX%rc6 GFXMHz  Pkg%pc6 PkgWatt CorWatt
-   -   10  0.49    1999    2000    552 0   0   26  6   168 234 311 0.00    0.03    0.02    2.73    16.78   79.96   0.03    99.22   0.00    39  100.01  1870.00 0.19    0.17
0   0   10  0.50    1999    2000    97  0   0   2   2   38  66  97  0.00    0.01    0.01    2.23    20.44   76.83   0.01    99.21   0.00    38  100.02  1870.00 0.19    0.17
1   1   14  0.68    1999    2000    119 0   0   1   1   16  56  58  0.00    0.00    0.01    1.01    16.54   81.76   0.00    99.12   0.00    38
2   2   3   0.14    1999    2000    36  0   0   1   0   11  7   76  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.76    2.38    96.72   0.00    99.73   0.00    39
3   3   13  0.63    1999    2000    300 0   0   22  3   103 105 80  0.00    0.12    0.04    6.92    27.78   64.54   0.12    98.82   0.00    39
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IRQ SMI POLL    C1  C6N C6S C7  C7S POLL%   C1% C6N%    C6S%    C7% C7S%    CPU%c1  CPU%c6  Mod%c6  CoreTmp GFX%rc6 GFXMHz  Pkg%pc6 PkgWatt CorWatt
-   -   9   0.47    1999    2000    552 0   1   17  11  165 214 312 0.00    0.02    0.03    2.57    16.75   80.17   0.02    99.26   0.00    39  100.00  1870.00 0.19    0.17
0   0   7   0.35    1999    2000    126 0   0   5   2   21  47  82  0.00    0.04    0.02    1.13    15.45   83.01   0.04    99.42   0.00    38  99.99   1870.00 0.19    0.17
1   1   14  0.72    1999    2000    90  0   0   0   1   19  39  46  0.00    0.00    0.02    1.21    11.59   86.48   0.00    99.11   0.00    38
2   2   7   0.37    1999    2000    156 0   0   5   2   61  57  112 0.00    0.02    0.03    3.96    20.06   75.56   0.02    99.29   0.00    39
3   3   9   0.45    1999    2000    180 0   1   7   6   64  71  72  0.00    0.02    0.06    3.96    19.92   75.61   0.02    99.23   0.00    39
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IRQ SMI POLL    C1  C6N C6S C7  C7S POLL%   C1% C6N%    C6S%    C7% C7S%    CPU%c1  CPU%c6  Mod%c6  CoreTmp GFX%rc6 GFXMHz  Pkg%pc6 PkgWatt CorWatt
-   -   13  0.65    1999    2000    750 0   0   29  25  321 290 322 0.00    0.02    0.07    4.98    20.01   74.27   0.02    98.99   0.00    39  100.01  1870.00 0.23    0.22
0   0   14  0.69    1999    2000    104 0   0   2   3   32  27  54  0.00    0.01    0.04    2.15    5.12    92.01   0.01    99.14   0.00    38  100.01  1870.00 0.23    0.22
1   1   12  0.62    1999    2000    136 0   0   4   2   21  68  70  0.00    0.01    0.03    1.32    17.39   80.65   0.01    99.14   0.00    38
2   2   6   0.29    2000    2000    92  0   0   7   5   51  65  118 0.00    0.02    0.05    3.23    23.49   72.95   0.02    99.36   0.00    39
3   3   20  1.01    1999    2000    418 0   0   16  15  217 130 80  0.00    0.05    0.18    13.24   34.05   51.50   0.05    98.34   0.00    39
root@mini:~#
```

I should point out the minipc served as windows 7 workstation in its previous life and never had issues on it. We used to use it for MS office application including Powerpoint.

Comment: Is the computer dusty/dirty, or in a dusty/dirty environment? Can you open the mini cabinet to check?

Comment: No it is not, the temp reading also indicate that.

Comment: make and model of processor? do `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`

Comment: Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: @heynnema no it is not. I just installed Ubuntu’s 20.04 server and did not make any custom overclocking settings

Comment: It is an older, not very common processor, with a low TDP of 10 watts. I wonder:If thermald is confused? If turbostat will work with it? Suggest to disable thermald, under controlled test conditions, watching temperature carefully. Suggest turbostat, if it works, as opposed to i7z.

Comment: I was able to install the package containing turbostat. output is at the end of the original post. I disabled thermald. But what do I replace it witth?

Comment: Don't replace with anything just yet. Run this: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,IRQ --interval 6` forever while you test, watching temperature. Add some load slowly, as you watch watts and temperature.

Comment: Both package watts and core watts seem rather low. Temperature O.K. , but no load.

Comment: turbo command: https://pastebin.com/hef0gauD

sensors: https://pastebin.com/7u16kBDz

Comment: I missed that you don't even have PkgTmp and need to use CoreTmp instead. Watts makes no sense.

Comment: Anyway, you don't seem to have a thermal problem. I suspect Thermald is confused, as is turbostat, so just leave it disabled.

Comment: mce means machine code exception, which shouldn't be from thermald. However, I can not find any such message anywhere in the kernel code.